# I can't find the last Nekker Nest. Does anyone have their locations pinned on a map?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've spent the last 1.5 hours running around trying to find the last Nekker Nest... I'm starting to think the quest is bugged. Has anyone got their locations pinned on a map?

Comment: It's not bugged, I found all of them after a while. I didn't mark them on a map, so I unfortunately can't tell you where exactly they are.

Comment: Hrm.. I found the first 3 in all of 2 minutes... I presume it's still all around the river / water fall area?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here is a Youtube video guide to the locations of the nests](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfmcFF3VoxE). All credits go to the guy who put it up, I just happen to find it online.

Comment: Hoeray for embedded Youtube :-)

Answer (score 22):

I've created a map containing the locations of all four Nekker nests. One of them is a bit further away, while the other three are clustered together and relatively easy to find.

[image]